# How to execute 3 functions sequentially?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, chain

I have noticed that jQuery does some functions async.
For example take a look to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvu51a8r/)

Html

```
<button id="click">
  TestMe
</button>
<div class="example">
  Hello
</div>
```

JS

```
var ex = $(".example").first();

$("#click").click(function() {
  ex.addClass("notransition")
    .width("100%")
    .removeClass("notransition");
})
```

CSS

```
.example {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.example.notransition {
  transition: none;
}
```

When you click the button the expected result is that the div should be expanded without animations because of class **.notransition** but this will not occur.

So how i can chain these three methods?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Use .done () function

```
var ex = $(".example").first();

 $("#click").click(function() {
 ex.addClass("notransition").width("100%").done(function(){
  ex.removeClass("notransition");
 })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ex = $(".example").first();

$("#click").click(function() {
  ex.addClass("notransition").width("100%").delay(1000).queue(function(){
    ex.removeClass("notransition");
  });
})
```

Seems to work well in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

As `addClass()` and `removeClass()` don't use queue they are executed simultaneously.

You can use [`.queue()`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)

```
var ex = $(".example").first();
$("#click").click(function() {
    ex.addClass("notransition").width("100%").delay(500).queue(function() {
        ex.removeClass("notransition").dequeue();
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0m4jcffy/1/)

---

Or simple [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```
var ex = $(".example").first();
$("#click").click(function() {
    ex.addClass("notransition").width("100%");
    setTimeout(function() {
        ex.removeClass("notransition").dequeue();
    },500);
});
```

Comment: The div in your example is still expanded with transition. So this doesn't work.

Comment: @koMah, See updated answer. It should be `.addClass("notransition").width("100%").delay(500)`